# Metadata API and Updating PageLayout

Tags: metadata-api

I am following the post "[Change Page Layout of objects using Meta data API in apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25139/change-page-layout-of-objects-using-meta-data-api-in-apex)" and trying to update the existing  pagelayout with multiple custom fields.

I am able to create a new section and add the field there but my requirement is " Add Multiple custom fields in the existing section say for Account Object page layout".

can anyone please help me with code snippet.

Comment: @andrefowcett , I saw the method addFieldToLayout() which is used to insert the field onto a new section in the existing PageLayout. Could you please tell, how can I add the field on the existing Section not in the new section .Also how to add more that one field on an existing section.